# Выбирает первый элемент из списка

Tags: javascript

Есть `ul`
При клике на `li` добавляю класс, но всегда добавляет первому в списке

Отслеживаю клик

```
 document.querySelector('.' + this.html_class.menu_toggle).addEventListener('click', (function () {
            this.toggleMenu();
        }).bind(this));
```

Добавляю класс

```
let element = e.target.closest('.' + this.html_class.menu_item_show_parent);
 element.classList.toggle(this.html_class.active);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы читали о [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)? Он возвращает только **первый** элемент по селектору, в то время как [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) вернёт коллекцию элементов по заданному селектору.

В этом случае потребуется пройтись циклом по всем найденным элементам и каждому повесить `.addEventListener()`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.'+this.html_class.menu_toggle).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.toggleMenu();
  });
});
```

Либо использовать [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).